# Correct way to link G+ local page with G+ business page

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-pages

I have two Google+ Pages:

- Google+ Business Page (address verified)
- What used to be a "Google Local" page (address verified)

They show as "locations" in the new Google My Business dashboard.

A few years back when Google migrated their Google Local "places" to Google+ pages, they made it possible to merge your existing G+ Business page with the G+ Local page. At the time I attempted this by clicking on "connect a different page" (on the old "Local" page settings) as explained in countless tutorials online, but the modal dialog box states "you don't own any non-local pages".

This is clearly incorrect because my G+ Business Page is a non-local page.

Or is it? I was able to verify the business address a few years ago, but it still doesn't show on Google Search Results, presumably because of this second problem I have: I can't update the address on the G+ Business Page.

Here's why. See below:

[image: G+ Locations Dashboard]

When I click the top entry to resolve the error status, it indicates there's a problem with the address, so I go to edit the address but the country option has a missing field:

[image: Missing Country Field]

If I try to save anyway, it errors with "one location can't be saved because it contains errors".

A year ago I contacted Google to resolve the problem and merge the pages, I even managed to make contact with a human being over the phone, but it was never followed-up and never resolved.

My end-goal is to allow people to review my business, and for this to connect to my existing G+ Business Page, that's all.